# x11 layout definition additional modifiers

Tags: linux, xorg, xkb

I am trying to create a new keyboard layout which has multiple layers. I succeeded in using Mod3 to Mod5 to implement those layers, but I would rather not use the ModX bits because applications do use them (emacs, desktop environments).

This is how I do it at this moment:

```
key <RWIN> {actions = [SetMods(modifiers= Mod3)]}
```

but I would rather do something along the lines

```
key <RWIN> {actions = [SetMods(modifiers= VirtualModifier1)]};
```

where VirtualModifier is not associated with one of the physical Mod3-Mod4 (*but* as I understund VirtualModifiers, they are just aliases to the real ones).

I was also thinking about using xkb groups where pressing  switches to a specific group and releasing it switches back, if that is possible.

Is it even possible to implement additional layers on a keyboard without using the Modifier bits?